# Subclassing NSBox

Tags: cocoa, subclassing, nsbox

How could I subclass a NSBox to change the width, height , font type and background color of the Box's title?.

Comment: `NSBox` is an `NSView` subclass, so you can subclass in and override `drawRect:` to do whatever you like. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of those look like they can be set with simple calls to NSBox's accessors, and the size and background color can be set by calling [myBox title] then calling the appropriate methods on the returned NSCell.

So subclassing NSBox to do all of these things would be as simple as setting the right properties in -init, and making sure to override the methods listed in the "Subclassing Notes" section within [NSBox's Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBox_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: could you help me with a example of how i could change the titlerect?

Comment: It's a plain C struct, so you should be able to do the following:

NSRect myRect = [myNSBox titleRect];
myRect.size.width = (CGFloat) whateverWidth;
myRect.size.height = (CGFloat) whateverHeight;